# Uncaught Error: Target container is not a DOM element. in React

Tags: reactjs, webpack

I encountered this error when trying to set up my React app. I have looked at other people's solution, but didn't seem to find the solution that works for me.

I normally just do create-react-app, but this time I try to configure webpack and I'm not sure what went wrong here.

my index.js and App.js files are both in the src folder and my index.html is inside the dist folder

THANK YOU FOR YOUR HELP

### my index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>High Five</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="app"></div>
    <script src="bundle.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

---

### my webpack.config.js

```
const webpack = require("webpack");
const path = require("path");
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require("mini-css-extract-plugin");

const config = {
  entry: ["react-hot-loader/patch", "./src/index.js"],
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, "dist"),
    filename: "bundle.js",
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
        use: "babel-loader",
        exclude: /node_modules/,
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: [MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader, "css-loader"],
      },
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        use: [MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader, "css-loader", "sass-loader"],
      },
      {
        test: /\.png$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: "url-loader",
            options: {
              mimetype: "image/png",
            },
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        test: /\.svg$/,
        use: "file-loader",
      },
    ],
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: [".js", ".jsx"],
    alias: {
      "react-dom": "@hot-loader/react-dom",
    },
  },
  devServer: {
    contentBase: "./dist",
  },
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      appMountId: "app",
      filename: "index.html",
    }),
    new MiniCssExtractPlugin(),
  ],
};

module.exports = config;
```

### index.js

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import App from "./App";
import "./styles.css";

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("app"));
```

### App.js

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { hot } from "react-hot-loader/root";

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Hello React</h1>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default hot(App);
```